# How to have variables accessible across keyframes- AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, parameter-passing, flash-cs5

I'm working on a portfolio suggestion application in Flash, which consists of two views: ask user for 3 to 4 points of information, and display recommendations based on that information.

The first view is going swimmingly, as all I need are the graphics to be created.  However, I'm having trouble understanding how a AS3 variable can be seen across keyframes when it was declared and initialized on the first frame.

The only multi-view app I've done is a Restaurant Guide flash app that was described in Adobe Flash CS5 Classroom in a Book.  In that example, the only AS function on four of the views 
was a stop() function.

If I were to do the same in this app, and declare the variables as global in the first frame, will they be accessible throughout?

**CLARIFICATION**

Two comments have said that my question is unclear, so I hope this makes my question more understandable.  I want to know how, if I gather all the user information on Frame 1 and then switch to a view on Frame 15, to access those variables on Frame 1.

Comment: "However, I'm having trouble understanding how a AS3 variable can be seen across keyframes when it was declared and initialized on the first frame." What it your question?

Comment: Your question is unclear, and the nature of it suggests to me that you are using AS3, but trying to code in a very old AS1 style of everything in framescripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really the way you're supposed to work in AS3.  Each view should be an object in your library with an associated class.  Your document should also have a class associated with it, and it is here that you would hold your common data.  The document class would instantiate each view as it is required and pass in the relevant variables.

That said, if you want to work the old way you shouldn't have trouble declaring a variable on frame 1 like this:

```
var myVar:String = "Hello!";
```

and then accessing it on frame 15 **of the same timeline** like this:

```
trace(myVar);
```

If that's what you're doing and it's not working then you'll need to update your question with some code examples.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  I had come across the trace command, but didn't know what it was used for